# How to make AuCTeX aware of the class in the master file?

Tags: emacs, auctex

When I divide a document between a master file and other buffers, I don't get hints from AucTeX to complete environments and macros. 
I set the master file with:

```
 %%% TeX-master: "mymasterfile"
```

Compilation and viewing work correctly. But, for example, if the master file uses beamer, pressing `C-c C-e` in a buffer, AuCTeX doesn't suggest me the `frame` environment (it does correctly in the master file). 
How can I make the buffer aware of the class load in the master file?

Comment: What do you get if you hit `C-h v TeX-parse-self RET` in your child file? Does it help if you hit `C-c C-n` in your master file and then in your child file as well?

Comment: `C-h v TeX-parse-self RET` gives   `t` as the current value of the variable. Actually, going back to the master and hitting `C-c C-n` there and in the child works! How can I make it autmoatic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AUCTeX manual has provides:

> ### 5.2 Multifile Documents
>
> [...]
>   AUCTeX keeps track of macros, environments, labels, and style files
>   that are used in a given document. For this to work with multifile
>   documents, AUCTeX has to have a place to put the information about the
>   files in the document. This is done by having an `auto` subdirectory
>   placed in the directory where your document is located. Each time you
>   save a file, AUCTeX will write information about the file into the
>   `auto` directory. When you load a file, AUCTeX will read the
>   information in the `auto` directory about the file you loaded and the
>   master file specified by `TeX-master`. Since the master file (perhaps
>   indirectly) includes all other files in the document, AUCTeX will get
>   information from all files in the document. This means that you will
>   get from each file, for example, completion for all labels defined
>   anywhere in the document.
>
> AUCTeX will create the `auto` directory automatically if `TeX-auto-save`
>   is `non-nil`. Without it, the files in the document will not know
>   anything about each other, except for the name of the master file.

Next section gives more information:

> ### 5.3 Automatic Parsing of TeX Files
>
> AUCTeX depends heavily on being able to extract information from the
>   buffers by parsing them. Since parsing the buffer can be somewhat
>   slow, the parsing is initially disabled. You are encouraged to enable
>   them by adding the following lines to your `.emacs` file.
>
> ```
> (setq TeX-parse-self t) ; Enable parse on load.
> (setq TeX-auto-save t) ; Enable parse on save.
> ```
>
> The latter command will make AUCTeX store the parsed information in an
>   `auto` subdirectory in the directory each time the TeX files are
>   stored. If AUCTeX finds the pre-parsed
>   information when loading a file, it will not need to reparse the
>   buffer. The information in the `auto` directory is also useful for
>   multifile documents, since it allows each file to
>   access the parsed information from all the other files in the
>   document. This is done by first reading the information from the
>   master file, and then recursively the information from each file
>   stored in the master file.
>
> The variables can also be done on a per file basis, by changing the
>   file local variables.
>
> ```
> %%% Local Variables:
> %%% TeX-parse-self: t
> %%% TeX-auto-save: t
> %%% End:
> ```
>
> Even when you have disabled the automatic parsing, you can force the
>   generation of style information by pressing <kbd>C-c C-n</kbd>. This is often the
>   best choice, as you will be able to decide when it is necessary to
>   reparse the file.

Comment: Thanks. I missed `(setq TeX-auto-save t)` in my `.emacs